# MySQL JOIN query with only one of several specific values

Tags: mysql

I have tables with one to many relationship.

```
rental
------
id
book_date

prices
------
rental_id
type_id
value
```

A normal JOIN query would give results

```
select * from rental a join prices b on a.id = b.rental_id;
```

---

```
id book_date  rental_id  type_id  value

1, 2016-10-04,  1,        8,       200
1, 2016-10-04,  1,       10,       300
2, 2016-10-04,  2,        8,       250
3, 2016-10-04,  3,        8,       200
3, 2016-10-04,  3,       10,       300
```

what I want is, if price record has type_id = 10, then take that row; if it doesn't, it's to take the row with type_id =8. The result I want:

```
1    2016-10-04    1    10    300
2    2016-10-04    2     8    250
3    2016-10-04    3    10    300
```

I have this query but it seems not to work on my case:

```
select * from rental a
join prices b 
on a.id = b.rental_id and 
      ( if(b.type_id = 10, b.type_id = 10, b.type_id = 8) )
ORDER BY a.id DESC LIMIT 20
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what I want is, if price record has type_id = 10 then it's only join
>   with type_id 10, if doesn't it's join with type_id =8

This means that the record with type_id 8 is to be *discarded* if there is 
*another* record with type_id 10. That "another" calls for another JOIN, a LEFT JOIN actually since the record to be compared might not exist:

```
SELECT a.*, b.* FROM rental a
JOIN prices b ON (a.id = b.rental_id)
LEFT JOIN prices check ON (a.id = check.rental_id AND check.type_id = 10)

WHERE b.type_id = 10 OR (b.type_id = 8 AND check.type_id IS NULL)
```

This means that the JOIN will get all type 8's and type 10's; then the LEFT JOIN will make it so the type 8's are taken only if there is no corresponding type 10:

```
       1 10 10
       2 8  10      # discarded
       2 10 10
       3 8  NULL
       4 15 NULL    # discarded
       4 8  NULL
```

ID 1 has only a 10 record, both query retrieve it, and it is accepted. ID 2 has both, so the 8-10 record is discarded because b type is 8, but c type is not NULL. ID 3 has only an 8 record, so the 10-seeking LEFT JOIN returns NULL, which fits the second part of the OR. ID 4 has type_ids 8 and 15, and the 15 one is discarded by both parts of the OR.

Answer (score 1):

> if price record has type_id = 10 then it's only join with type_id 10, if doesn't it's join with type_id =8

This logic can be enforced by choosing the record with the maximum `type_id` for every `rental_id`.  If so, then you can simply add a third join condition which will restrict the result set to only records matching this extra condition:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*
FROM rental a
INNER JOIN prices b
    ON a.id = b.rental_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT rental_id,
           CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN type_id = 10 THEN 1 END) = 1 THEN 10
                WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN type_id = 8 THEN 1 END)  = 1 THEN 8
                ELSE MAX(type_id)
           END AS type_id
    FROM prices
    GROUP BY rental_id
) c
    ON b.rental_id = c.rental_id AND
       b.type_id   = c.type_id
```

**Follow the link below for a running demo:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: Sorry forget to mention, actually 10 is not the maximum of type_id, there are several greater numbers then 10. So I think I cannot use the maximum to choose. If 10 exists use 10, if not use 8 instead. thanks :)